# Missing product attributes in Commerce.js API response

Tags: api, attributes, product, missing-data, commerce.js

I've had an issue when sending requests to fetch products from the Commerce.js API.

It's that I cannot retrieve the list of attributes I set for each product from the UI that this service provides.

Product Attributes

[image]

API Response

[image]

In the [API docs](https://commercejs.com/docs/api/#list-all-products), it is shown that it's possible to fetch the attributes of each product.

Otherwise, would you please suggest any alternative to Commerce.js that is highly customizable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. In case you used Commerce SDK, I tried that at first but it seems that it doesn't return the attributes. Instead you can try retrieving the products using the fetch API with the secret key. That worked for me

Comment: I didn't use the public key that's the reason.
Thanks for your answer it works using the secret key.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Attribute itself set to Visible, it's by default Private that can't be fetched

[image: 1]